# Delayed travel with United Airlines

Tags: air-travel, delays, united-airlines

On 19th April, we left on a Lufthansa flight to Frankfurt - UA8848.  The departure was then delayed.  So we arrived late and missed our connecting flight which was due to depart at 9.00 to Heathrow (original target arrival time was 09.40).

We had to take a flight from Frankfurt to Munich (about 10.00 am).

We then had to take a flight from Munich (about 11.30) to Heathrow) arrival time about 1.00 pm).

I am trying to track what time the flight from Munich to Heathrow actually arrived on the 20th April, so I can see how delayed the arrival time was, from the original one of 09.40.

How can I track this?

Comment: We had been travelling for more than 24 hours at the time, so yes potentially but we didn't. That doesn't really answer my question does it?

Comment: I'm surprised that they had to reroute you via Munich... Lufthansa has a FRA-LHR flight at 10am, another at noon...

Comment: @jcaron Presumably, those were full.

Comment: Yes all direct flights were full as it was Easter weekend

Answer (score 1):

[Flightradar24's data](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/lh463) for this flight only goes back one week, but you can use a free trial subscription to see farther back than that, which should answer your question.